# MyBatis issue: Unrecognized jdbcType

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, sqlexception

While trying to convert my app from using MyBatis [it was iBatis before], I've been getting the following error, in spite of trying to make so many different kinds of changes to the code: What am I doing wrong? Any help would be really really really great!!!

```html
Error message:    
`Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: ### Error querying database.  Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10271][10296][3.58.82] Unrecognized JDBC type: -10. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null
`
`### The error may exist in Path-to-XML-File.XML`
`### The error may involve namespace.resultMap-name`
`### The error occurred while executing a query`
`### SQL: {call name-of-stored-proc(?)}`
`### Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10271][10296][3.58.82] Unrecognized JDBC type: -10. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null`
`; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [-4228]; [jcc][10271][10296][3.58.82] Unrecognized JDBC type: -10. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10271][10296][3.58.82] Unrecognized JDBC type: -10. ERRORCODE=-4228, SQLSTATE=null`



XML File:    `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="Namespace-name">
 <resultMap id="retrieveReports-results" type="Folder-structure-to-Java-file" autoMapping="true">
  <result property="name" column="REPORT_NAME"/>
  <result property="location" column="REPORT_DIRECTORY"/>
  <result property="key" column="REPORT_KEY"/>
  <result property="executable" column="EXECUTABLE"/> 
  <result property="commandLine" column="COMMAND_LINE"/> 
  <result property="commandLineFormat" column="COMMAND_LINE_FORMAT"/>  
 </resultMap>
<select id="retrieveReports" resultType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE">
   {call prc_sel_reports(#{reports,jdbcType=CURSOR,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,mode=OUT,resultMap=retrieveReports-results})}
 </select>
</mapper>`

Java code:    
  
  try {
    
   List < Report > reports = super.getSqlSession().selectList("retrieveReports");
   if(log.isDebugEnabled()){
    log.debug("Retrieved " + reports.size() + " reports, in method: retrieveReports()");
   }
      
   return reports;
   
   // Attempt to catch different kinds of exceptions.
  } catch (Exception e) {  
   throw new RuntimeException("Exception caught while trying to retrieve reports", e);
  }
```

Comment: Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a *parameterType* in the select statement, either map or custom class. An instance has to be passed on statement invocation.
*resultType* is not used, then irrelevant.

Procedure actually writes in a field of the "input" parameter passed to mybatis statement, and the statement does not return anything.

Mapper interface would be: `void retrieveReports(Map<String, Object> params);`
And your call:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
session.selectList("retrieveReports", params);
List<Report> reports = (List<Report>)params.get("reports");
```

Param may also be a custom type with property `private List<Report> reports;`.